# Swift - Alamofire response Vs WKWebView response

Tags: ios, swift, jsoup, alamofire, wkwebview

I am working on Alamofire in Swift 4, lets have a look in below codes

**Using WKWebView**

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML") { (result, error) in
        do {
            let document1 = try SwiftSoup.parse(result as! String)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    }
}
```

**Using Alamofire**

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .get).responseString(completionHandler: { response in
        if let htmlString = response.result.value {
            do {
                let document2 = try SwiftSoup.parse(htmlString)
            } catch let error {
                print("Error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
    })
```

In both case I am loading a same URL and parsing the response into SwiftSoup element, but the issue is I found some tags/class names are missing when I am parsing response of Alamofire. Any clue why?

Comment: Webviews would automatically add some missing tags, e.g. `html`, `head` etc. You are not reading the original data but the DOM.

Comment: some tags are missing from deeper in path, for example somewhere in a div under body...I guess alamofire returns before full load or something like this...

Comment: @Sulthan do you mean the DOM will change from original data?

Comment: That's normal behavior of browsers that some tags (not in body) are added. Also note that if the page contains javascript, it can also affect the internal structure of the DOM. You are not displaying the response data, you are displaying DOM of a dynamic web page. You would have to add a better example and a way to reproduce the issue. We cannot help otherwise.